# "res.end" is not a function in "res.on('end', () =>" (express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get confused on how to show json result I've got from api on my webpage

I am using express.js + node.js, and Bing API

here is my code

```
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var port = 8000;

const SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
if (!SUBSCRIPTION_KEY) {
  throw new Error('error no keys')
}

app.use(express.static("example.com"));

function bingWebSearch(query) {
  https.get({
    hostname: 'api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
    path:     '/bing/v7.0/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query),
    headers:  { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY },
  }, res => {
    let body = ''
    res.on('data', part => body += part)
    res.on('end', () => {

      // yes this could work and print out result json at my terminal
      console.dir(JSON.parse(body), { colors: false, depth: null })

      // but why this can not work with error msg I posted below
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
      // I cant even output this on my webpage, and actually I want to print of course the result json

    })
    res.on('error', e => {
      console.log('Error: ' + e.message)
      throw e
    })
  })
}

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {

  const searchString = `${req.query.q}`;
  bingWebSearch(searchString);

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Your app is ready! Navigate to: http://localhost:' + port + '/.'));
```

and error msg here

```
/var/www/bing-web-search.js:27
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      ^
/var/www/bing-web-search.js:28
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
      ^
TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function
TypeError: res.end is not a function
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (/var/www/bing-web-search.js:31:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

p.s. if I move line 27,28 into app.get

```
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {

  const searchString = `${req.query.q}`;
  bingWebSearch(searchString);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));

});
```

They worked fine to appear on my webpage

So I just don't know how to make my result also shown on my webpage

Any tip or help would be appreciate, thank you!

Comment: Using *https* is really low level, and not really recommended if not strictly necessary. You should look into using something like [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) or similar module and use promises instead of callbacks. There are many modules which simplifies this process a lot.

Comment: @Enslev Ah thank you, this was completing copied from Bing API document. I will try another way, really thank you for your kindly remind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about a very basic concept of programming, called scope. And you are actually very close to the solution. You can read about scope in Javascript [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Within calling of `GET /api`, another function `bingWebSearch(searchString)` gets called. `bingWebSearch` has its own scope. So the `res` variable from `GET /api` is not available there.

Also, within bingWebSearch you make a `https.get` request, and you're naming the return value `res` as well.

One solution would be to pass the res variable of `GET /api` as an argument:

```
bingWebSearch(searchString, res)
```

But then of course you need to rename the return value of `https.get`. You could call it `response`.

Would look like this:

```
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
   bingWebSearch(searchString, res);
});

function bingWebSearch(query, res) {
   https.get({
      ...
   }, response => {
      let body = ''
      response.on('data', part => body += part)
      response.on('end', () => {
         res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
      }
   }
}
```

Another solution would be to actually `return` the JSON string from bingWebSearch and then call `res.setHeader` and `res.end` within `app.get("/api")`.

I think I'd prefer that one, as I think it is more readable. But then you'd have to consider that `https.get` gets called async. So if you try to just return its result, there won't be a result yet. But that is a topic on its own and not within the scope of your question. Quentin's answer has some hints on it.

Comment: OMG IT WORKS SO GREAT THANK YOU FOR SAVING MY LIFE!!!

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. Would you mind accepting my answer? (Click on the checkmark) @alexh1994

Answer (score 1):

You have two different variables named `res`. They have completely different values.

The `res` defined here:

> ```
> app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
> ```

… is the object representing the response you are going to **send** from Express to the client.

The `res` defined here:

> ```
> }, res => {
> ```

… is the object representing the response you **received** from Bing.

---

You are trying to treat the response from Bing as if it was the response you are sending to the client.

Since it isn't, it fails. It fails in the particular way you are seeing because the APIs for the two objects are different.

---

**You need to put the data from the `bingWebSearch(searchString);` response in the same place as the Express response object.** Using different variable names for the two `res` variable wouldn't be a bad idea either, it would make the code less confusing.

Since you are using `https.get` you can do that by passing in a callback function which closes over the Express `res` variable, but it would probably be easier to wrap it in a promise instead. It would be even easier to replace `https.get` with an API that uses promises by default (e.g. Axios).

Further reading: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

```
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var port = 8000;

const SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
if (!SUBSCRIPTION_KEY) {
  throw new Error('error no keys')
}

app.use(express.static("example.com"));

function bingWebSearch(query) {
  https.get({
    hostname: 'api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
    path:     '/bing/v7.0/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query),
    headers:  { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY },
  }, (req, res) => {
    let body = ''
    res.on('data', part => body += part)
    res.on('end', () => {

      // yes this could work and print out result json at my terminal
      console.dir(JSON.parse(body), { colors: false, depth: null })

      // but why this can not work with error msg I posted below
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
      // I cant even output this on my webpage, and actually I want to print of course the result json

    })
    res.on('error', e => {
      console.log('Error: ' + e.message)
      throw e
    })
  })
}

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {

  const searchString = `${req.query.q}`;
  bingWebSearch(searchString);

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Your app is ready! Navigate to: http://localhost:' + port + '/.'));
```

express returns the response in the second parameter of the function not in the first. so I corrected it on line number 18.

Comment: https.get only returns the response to the callback function, according to the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_url_options_callback. So `(req, res) => { }` will result in `res` being `undefined`.